# gopacket ubuntu16.04 error undefined: pcapErrorNotActivated

Tags: go, gopacket

root@ubuntu:~/processNet/processNet# go run testversion.go

## github.com/google/gopacket/pcap

/home/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:30:22: undefined: pcapErrorNotActivated
/home/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:52:17: undefined: pcapTPtr
/home/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:64:10: undefined: pcapPkthdr

````
import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println(pcap.Version())
}```

Already installed libpcap and c test available
````

Answer (score 0):

libpcap alone is not enough，libpcap-dev is also required:

```
sudo apt install libpcap-dev
```

which package is named libpcap-devel in centos:

```
sudo yum install libpcap-devel
```

I solved my problem after the installation.